# Svn remote Server certificate verification issue by php

Tags: php, windows, svn, ssl-certificate, proc-open

In order to use websvn for browsing remote repository, I installed websvn in my localhost(windows7, wampserver).
Websvn executes svn commands by proc_open of php functions.
When svn command is:

`svn info "http://site.com/svnurl" --xml --non-interactive --username "guest" --password "guest"`

proc_open returns correct result.
But when svn command is:

`svn info "https://site.com/svnurl" --non-interactive --trust-server-cert --username "guest" --password "guest"`

proc-open returns errors.

svn: E175002: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'https://site.com/svnurl'
svn: E175002: OPTIONS of 'https://site.com/svnurl': Server certificate verification failed: certificate issued for a different hostname, issuer is not trusted (https://site.com/svnurl).

Here, site.com/svnurl is unreal url, real url is 205.174.169.180:9880/GBoomTest.ca.

How can you fix this problem?

Comment: Part of the error message is that the certificate is issued for a different host name.  What is the host defined in the cert?  I'm guessing it's not `site.com`